# Java - How to split strings based on certain length ?

Tags: java, android, substring, c-strings

I want to split this number based on length  : 11101204 . Like Division would be 111. Division2=01,Division3=2,Divison 4=04; i.e., 111, 01 , 12, 04 ...I want it to be split in this way and if the number has only 3 numbers then Division should be 111 and rest should be null How can I achieve this ? 
Many Thanks !

Comment: There's something called `substring`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `String.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)`

```
String string = "11101204";

System.out.println(string.substring(0, 3));
System.out.println(string.substring(3, 5));
System.out.println(string.substring(5, 6));
System.out.println(string.substring(6, 8));
```

Output:

```
111
01
2
04
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for regular expressions.  Your example isn't self-consistent, so you'll have to define your requirements more clearly and adjust the regex to match.

The regex `"(\\d{3})(\\d{2})?"` would match "111" or "11101", but not "1110" because the second capturing group (what you've called a "division") is not the required two digits.  When a string matches, you would use `Matcher#group(int)` to get the groups.  For groups that weren't matched, it will return either null or an empty string depending on whether the expression in the group can match an empty string.